# Why jackson.YAML replaces `is_error` with `_error` field?

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, yaml

The following Kotlin code prints `_error: false` instead of `is_error: false`.

How to change it so it keeps the original `is_error` name?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator

fun to_yaml(v: Any): String {
  val mapper = ObjectMapper(
  YAMLFactory()
    .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)
    .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER)
    .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES)
//      .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS)
//      .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.LITERAL_BLOCK_STYLE)
  )
  mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
  return mapper.writeValueAsString(v)
}

class Result(
  val is_error: Boolean
)

fun main() {
  println(to_yaml(Result(false)))
}
```

Comment: The field should be named `error`, not `is_error`. This result probably happens due to the fact that "is" and "has" are the magic prefixes for boolean field accessors, like "get"  is for normal fields: `data` -> `getData`, `error` -> `hasError` / `isError` and there is some logic in place that removes those prefixes. No idea though how to disable that behaviour in this case.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks, but I can't change the field name, as it's a shared schema, used in multiple projects with multiple languages.

Comment: In Java it would be `@JsonProperty("is_error")` on the field, not sure how this works in Kotlin though.